# URL parsing only working explicit

Tags: python, url-parsing, urlparse

I'm reading URL's from a .csv file and I'm trying to parse them. Why do I only get correct values in **scheme** and **netloc** when I put the link explicit in the function `urlparse(...)`, see variable `o2` and not when I give `newsource` in `urlparse`?

```
for line in file:
    source = str(line.split(",")[2])
    print("ORIGINAL URL: \n" + source)
    newsource = source.replace('"',"")
    print("REMOVING QUOTES: \n" + newsource)
    newsource.strip
    print("STRIPPING SPACES: \n" + newsource + "\n")
    o = urlparse(newsource)
    print("RESULT PARSING: " + str(o) + "\n")
    o2 = urlparse("http://nl.aldi.be/aldi_vlees_609.html")
    print("RESULT MANUAL PARSING: " + str(o2) + "\n")
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: @wim I changed that but still didn't work

Comment: we are not mind-readers here, you will have to show us what you've changed and better describe what isn't working before we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see from the failed parse that you have a leading space character, which would cause the same problem you have:

```
>>> urlparse.urlparse(' http://nl.aldi.be/aldi_vlees_609.html')
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path=' http://nl.aldi.be/aldi_vlees_609.html', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

This line does nothing:

```
newsource.strip
```

You probably wanted:

```
newsource = newsource.strip()
```

Comment: Why doesn't newsource.strip() works like newsource = newsource.strip()?

Comment: @Stanko strip doesn't change the state of the current object, so you need to assign to something else as string is immutable.